# Using a data text file in Colab to calculate mean

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, text-files

I am new to python so any assistance is greatly appreciated.
I am writing a calculator to generate mean from a text file in google colab.

I am able to calculate the mean by hardcoding numbers, and I am also able to access a text file in a separate piece of code.
My issue is passing the data in the txt file to the mean function.

```
'''
####This writes data in from txt file
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/data.txt' 

with open(filename) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()
    
for line in lines:
   print(line)
'''


'''
 #Calculating the Mean
def calculate_mean(numbers):
  s=sum(numbers)
  N=len(numbers)
# Calculate the mean
  mean=s/N

  return mean

if __name__=='__main__':
  
  donations =[100,100,200,1000]
  mean=calculate_mean(donations)
  N= len(donations)
  print('Mean donation over the last {0} days is {1}'.format(N,mean))
'''
```

Question
how do i modify 'donations' to obtain the list from the text file data.txt instead of the hardcoded values

Here is a screenshot of values in the txt file.  This is a learning exercise for me.
[image: data]

Again many thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of your data file?

Comment: What is the content of your data.txt file?

Comment: The file has only three values on the top three lines. it's a sample file i created in two seconds
1
2
3

i placed a screenshot of the data in the initial post

Comment: if I am understanding your question correctly then You have to mount google drive in the Colab to read any file and then you can copy it's path and directly as you do on your local system. Read the content as Data frame or Array and do the desired operations

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I mount the drive in colab, but my knowledge of python is not so good. 

this part of the code works
####This writes data in from txt file
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/data.txt' 

with open(filename) as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()
    
for line in lines:
   print(line)

but i cannot figure out how to assign the values in the file to 'donations' if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so you are a little out of sorts here.
You need to parse the incoming data based on the format. If your delimiter is a space as in your example, the following code should work.

```
     #Calculating the Mean
    def calculate_mean(numbers):
      s=sum(numbers)
      N=len(numbers)
    # Calculate the mean
      mean=s/N    
      return mean
    
    if __name__=='__main__':
         ####This writes data in from txt file
         filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/data.txt' 
    
         with open(filename) as file_object:
              lines = file_object.readlines()
        
         for line in lines:
              print(line)
              donations_as_strings=line.split(" ") # " " is you delimiter
              donations = map(int,donations_as_strings) # If using python 2.X
              donations = list(map(int,donations_as_strings)) # if using python 3.X
              # or just do this
              donations = [int(i) for i in donations_as_strings]
              mean=calculate_mean(donations)
              print(donations) # Should be [#,#,#]
              N= len(donations)
              print('Mean donation over the last {0} days is {1}'.format(N,mean))
```

Comment: Thanks! When i run this code it throws an error 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
for s=sum(numbers) and  donations =line.split(" ")
when i try to convert to int it essentially says int must be used with a string not a list.
how would i convert this to int values?

Comment: Added lines to convert to int. Please check python version and apply correct line. Also added a line that should work for both

Comment: thanks you so much! that worked. i cannot say i completely understand it all, but it works!  thanks for the help